# How to initialize multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I want to initialize an n x n x n x ... x n dimensional array where n shows up k times.

Assume n = 10.

The k = 2 case is creating a 10 x 10 array with : `arr = np.array((10,10))`

The k = 3 case is creating a 10 x 10 x 10 array with: `arr = np.array((10,10,10))`

How can I do this? The purpose of this approach is to implement a chi-squared minimization with a grid search. The grid is an n x n x n x ... x n dimensional array where n shows up k times (k is the number of free parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an n x n ... x n array, you can use `(n,)*k` to get a tuple specifying the dimensions.  That is `(10,)*5 = (10, 10, 10, 10, 10)`.  For constructing an array:

```
arr = np.zeros((n,)*k)
```

Other construction commands, `ones`, `empty`, etc, may also be useful.

To make sure we're on the same page with nomenclature, you should also note that the question states something which is wrong: `arr = np.array((10,10,10))` does not give a "10 x 10 x 10 array", but simply an array of three tens.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it a tuple representation of a generator expression or a list comprehension.  Something like this:

```
tuple((n for i in range(k))) # n = 10, k = 5 in this case

(10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize array with zeroes , you can use `numpy.zeros` and pass it the shape of the array.

Example -

```
import numpy as np

k = 5
n = 10
narr = np.zeros(tuple(n for _ in range(k)))

print(narr.shape)
```

Above example would create a 10x10x10x10x10 array. Please note if k is 10 or higher numbers, numpy may not be able to handle that big arrays.